# How can loops occur in static routing?

Tags: routing

I would like to learn how can loops occur in static routing? Plus if someone can give some example scenarios I would be glad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most trivial example is when router A has a static route (for a certain network) that has router B as next hop, and router B has a static route (for the same network) with router A as next hop, then you have a loop.

So router A:

```
interface serial0
  description Link to router B
  ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.252

ip route 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.0.0.2
```

And router B:

```
interface serial0
  description Link to router A
  ip address 10.0.0.2 255.255.255.252

ip route 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.0.0.1
```

Now, when either A or B receives a packets destined for 192.168.x.x the packet will loop between A and B until the TTL expires.